# How to use lsqcurvefit to fit a rational function?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I want to fit a rational function using the curve fitting technique in MATLAB.

I am trying to use `lsqcurvefit` to reproduce a rational function `M`, which takes 5 inputs, with the data outputted from the exact function `C`. I think I am close to getting the plots; however, when I use `lsqcurvefit`, I keep getting an error saying:

> LSQCURVEFIT requires the following inputs to be of data type double: 'YDATA'.

Below is my code:

```
% Define range for k
k= linspace(1E-10,1.5,100); 

% Exact Function C(k)
C= @(k)(0.5*((1i*k+0.135).* (1i*k+0.651)))./((1i*k+0.0965).* (1i*k+0.4555));

% Cget function used to extract real and imaginary numbers and stacks the result
Cget= @(k)[real(C(k)); imag(C(k))]; 

%Call function Cget(k) to get stacked real and imaginary values
realimag =Cget(k);

% Create an initial guess
x0=[1,1];

% Define parameters
a1=0.2; a2=0.7; b1=0.1; b2=0.5;

% Define approximated function 
M= @(a1,a2,b1,b2,k)(0.5*((1i*k+a1).* (1i*k+a2)))./((1i*k+b1).* (1i*k+b2));
Mget1= @(a1,a2,b1,b2,k)[real(M(a1,a2,b1,b2,k)); imag(M(a1,a2,b1,b2,k))]; 
T=Mget1(a1,a2,b1,b2,k);

%Find best fit curve
x=lsqcurvefit(M,x0,k,C)
```

How can I fit reproduce `M`, given the exact function `C`?

Comment: YData in your case is `C`. It should be `double`. You have it as an anonymous function.

Comment: what do you mean by double? That's the part I don't understand...

Comment: double data type

Comment: @SardarUsama Do you have any suggestions to fix that?

Comment: I can see your code but I don't really know what you're implementing because you haven't told us that. What nonlinear curve fitting problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Basically, I am using a rational function that would fit the Bessel function data. So I am trying to use the nonlinear curve fitting function to fit my rational function (M) to the Bessel function (C).

Comment: In other words, I am trying to fit the data that I get from the Bessel function using the nonlinear curve fit function...

Comment: Please do not delete your question if someone has answered. I know the system lets you (in certain circumstances), but it's perceived as rude towards the person who put effort into answering. If you want to no longer have your account associated with this post, you can fill out the contact form and moderators can then disconnect it.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `C` should be entered as a double array so that the function should get the input range and use it in the calculation.

```
% Exact Function C(k)- Bessel Function
C0 = (0.5*((1i*k+0.135).* (1i*k+0.651)))./((1i*k+0.0965).* (1i*k+0.4555));
```

and parameters of `x` could be entered as an array with 4 values.

```
M = @(x,k)(0.5*((1i*k+x(1)).* (1i*k+x(2))))./((1i*k+x(3)).* (1i*k+x(4)));
```

and `x0` should have 4 values.

```
x0 = [1,1,1,1]; 
%Find best fit curve
x = lsqcurvefit(M,x0,k,C0)
```